# Хочу создать DialogFragment по примеру. Ошибка

Tags: android

из Fragmenta вызываю Dialog. делаю по примеру Вот ссылка [link text](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

Она  выдает ошибку? как исправить

The method show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)

public class FragmentThree extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_three, container,
            false);

    view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

***_***____ошибка show

```
                    DialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
                    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```

Comment: newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");


The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: extends FragmentActivity{

Comment: или в твоем случае getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Activity

Comment: измени Activity на FragmentActivity

Comment: изменил толку нет 
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Activity

Comment: не может быть, у тебя та же ошибка, а должно уже быть FragmentActivity вместо Activity, разберись и определись, что ты используешься: support-library или api 3

Comment: я этот пример изменяю http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/ 
в классе FragmentThree.java я добавил кнопку и вызываю диалог

Comment: @Ильмир Сулейманов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```

to

```
 newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```

Comment: спс все решил ошибку